# GParted не позволяет увеличить раздел

Tags: linux, gparted

Ни к sda5, ни к sda6 не выходит добавить свободную память, как вы видите там 16гб свободно. Загружаюсь с Live CD.

Даже если я забираю немного памяти у sda 6 (у меня появляется отдельные 10гб, к примеру), к sda5 я всеравно не могу их прибавить. То есть у меня уже висит отдельно 16, отдельно 10, и sda5 все равно не хочет расширятся.[image]

Comment: 6 и 7 разделы нужно подвинуть в самый конец. Раздел не может быть разорван.

Comment: Не очень понял, что значит подвинуть разделы в самый конец, обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: правой по sda7, там будет resize/move, двигаем в конец. Потом то же с sda6. И после этого появится возможность расширить sda5